# Is necessary to use ClamTK with ClamAV?

Tags: security, antivirus, clamav, clamtk

Do I need to install Clam TK when using Clam AV?  Clam TK will not install.  Will Clam AV run automatically in the background?

Answer (score 2):

ClamAV is a scanner tool and only scan what the user tell it to scan. It does not run on the background, at least by default.

There is no need to use ClamTK to make ClamAV work. It is just a plus for people how don't like terminal and prefer buttons instead. You can still use ClamAV using the command line.

Comment: Your welcome! Remember your can [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) & upvote it!